# Where is a SiteLogoUrl in CSOM?

Tags: web, sharepoint-2013, graphical-logo, csom

I found [SPWeb.SiteLogoUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.sitelogourl.aspx) and expected this property in CSOM and REST. But I didn't find it. How can I get a SiteLogoUrl using CSOM or REST?

[SP.js](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245288.aspx)

[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web_properties.aspx)

Comment: This issue was fixed in build 15.0.4605.1000 and in SPO. So newer SP2013 and all SPO should be without this problem when you use newer client dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was moved to the POST request that SharePoint creates while redirecting via appredirect.aspx. So, the only one way to get Site Logo Url is to handle appredirect POST request.

To initiate redirect you should use this code snippet:

```
Response.Redirect(TokenHelper.GetAppContextTokenRequestUrl(sharePointHostUrl, Server.UrlEncode(targetUrl)));
```

ContextToken, SiteLogo, Url, Title and so on can be found in the POST FormData.