# Change SiteLogo via csom in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

Regarding to this Question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313303/where-is-a-sitelogourl-in-csom).

How can i change the siteLogo to a new one?

Is it even possible to do it from a ConsoleApplication via CSOM?

Comment: Why the hell was this closed? It's perfectly clear what he's asking - he wants to set the SiteLogoUrl property of a Site via Client Side Object Model. 

You should have moved this to SharePoint Stack Exchange instead of shutting it down as "unclear".

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are no hooks to the site logo in the client object model like there is in the regular object model.  (`site.RootWeb.SiteLogoUrl = pictureUrl;`)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to do it using the CSOM but you can create a new site collection scoped (for SharePoint Online) feature with an event receiver and deploy it as a solution. It worked for me and saved me manually updating 380 sites. I had the FeatureActivated method recursively set the logo on the root web of the site collection and all of the sub webs. Here is the code:

```
public class Feature1EventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{

    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
        if (site != null)
        {
            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
            SetLogo(web);
        }
    }

    private void SetLogo(SPWeb web) {
        web.SiteLogoUrl = "/SiteAssets/logo.png";
        web.Update();
        foreach (SPWeb subweb in web.Webs)
        {
            SetLogo(subweb);
        }
    }
}
```